# Excel sheet comments in C#

Tags: c#, excel, aspose-cells

I have a list that is filtered from SQL and an excel sheet that stocks them. In that list I have a column named A. 
If that column exists, a comment should appear at the header of that column. 
Its position might change, so I **can't** use  this:

```
int commentIndex = worksheet.Comments.Add("F5");
Comment comment = worksheet.Comments[commentIndex];
comment.Note = "Hello Aspose!";
```

Here is my column

```
if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName==A)
{
    // code to be filled
}
```

dt=data table that has the columns from SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is I did it and solved the issue:

```
int commentIndex = ws.Comments.Add(0, i);
    Aspose.Cells.Comment comment = ws.Comments[commentIndex];
comment.Note = "Blalala";
```